# MariaDB doesnt see mac desktop files through terminal

Tags: xampp, mariadb

When I try to insert a file file into MariaDB through the terminal in XAMPP, if the file is on my Desktop, I get an error :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/buzz/Desktop/FEM/data/test_1.csv' 
INTO TABLE food2_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS (food, calories, carbs, potassium, protein, fiber, unit, notes)
;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/Users/buzz/Desktop/FEM/data/test_1.csv' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

It is only if I put the file into the shared drive which appears when I mount XAMPP, that XAMPP can access it.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '/opt/lampp/htdocs/test_1.csv' 
INTO TABLE food2_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS (food, calories, carbs, potassium, protein, fiber, unit, notes)
;
```

Why? How can I use files from my desktop? Also, why do I have to mount XAMPP as an external drive? Why wouldn't the files be in my mac's local drive?

Thanks

Comment: What MacOs version are you on? Catalina?

Comment: @GeneZ.Ragan high sierra

Comment: `LOAD DATA` is a bit confusing when it comes to accessing the file.  Notice that you said `LOCAL` in one case, but not the other.